# What is best way to build a 3-d scene of underground pipeline precisely and closer to reality with the real world coordinate?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I am doing a project about underground pipeline visualization and monitoring. I met some problem in the process of building the 3d scene of the pipeline. Firstly , i use openGL to build the whole 3d scene , which i found it's difficult to do simulation of the pipeline corners , valve and etc(Forgive me i am a green hand in openGL) .So I turned to 3dsmax in which i could build the model easily and use some nice textures. But think about this fact , if we have a pipeline corner in the real world (suppose it is a quarter part of a torus ) , when i load it in openGL , after doing the stretch ,translation ,rotation to put it in a precise place , the radius of the pipe built in 3dmax is also stretched . I found myself in a dilemma. Any idea to solve this problem(if there exist a better way) is appreciated . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what kind of stretch is applied? _"after doing the **stretch** ,translation ,rotation"?_ Isn't it normal that it stretched radius too?

Comment: yes , but the problem is i don't want it be stretched, at a corner ,the radius can be different (not the radius of pipe ) ,thus it should be stretched in different degree .But the radius of pipe doesn't change. So I guess 3ds model can't help to solve this problem ,the real world varies .

Comment: You could build dynamically the outside of the pipe giving only lines to a geometry shader, that will create rings with fixed size. With some custom vertex attributes you could get decorations and more.

Comment: use 3ds models for fixed size things like valves joints ,... and generate pipes as GL_QUAD_STRIP just generate 2 set of points on circle for normal tube (simple for (a=0;a<2*M_PI;a+=0.01*M_PI) with r*sin(a) and r*cos(a) ... just remember transform matrix for each pipe and convert circle x,y, to it. For curved pipes do the same but segmentate the tube into more sub tubes along the curve) the join can be done also by quad strip just connect neigbouring pipes rings together for curved pipes

Comment: I have thought about the idea before. Build meshes . In this way , i have to do a lot of coordinate calculations . So i put it aside. Now , I am making a compromise that the joints are rare and of limited types .But still , using meshes is a workable solution.